# Comparing the same column in a table for different rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I have table in my MySQL table which is of the following format:

```
 |Result|month|Name|
 |   1  | Nov |  x | 
 |   1  | Nov |  y | 
 |   1  | Nov |  z | 
 |   2  | Dec |  x | 
 |   2  | Dec |  y | 
 |   1  | Dec |  z |
```

I'm trying get the count of name where result for Nov is not the same as the result for dec. For the above example it is 2. I tried the following query, but I don't seem to get the out put as expected:

```
$query =  SELECT A.Result as t1,B.Result as t2 from MonthlyState A INNER JOIN MonthlyState B ON A.Result = B.Result WHERE A.month = 'Nov' AND B.month = 'Dec'


$result=mysql_query($query);


$count1 = 0;
$count2 = 0;

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

  if ((string)$r['t1'] == (string)$r['t2']  ) {
        $count1 = $count1 + 1;

  }else{
        $count2 = $count2 + 1; 
  }

}
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```sql
SELECT A.Result as t1,B.Result
FROM MonthlyState A
INNER JOIN MonthlyState B ON A.name = B.name
WHERE A.month = 'Nov'
  AND B.month = 'Dec'
  AND b.result != a.result
```

If you want to get the COUNT directly you can do:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MonthlyState A
INNER JOIN MonthlyState B ON A.name = B.name
WHERE A.month = 'Nov'
  AND B.month = 'Dec'
  AND b.result != a.result;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d133aa/3)</kbd>

Comment: What if I would need to find those with same result?

Comment: You would change the last line from `!=` to `=`

Comment: @SiddharthanAsokan. Nop. in sql you only use one `=` sign

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  name
FROM MonthlyState
WHERE month IN ('Nov','Dec')
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Result) > 1
```